# Not able to sign up in firebase with android using email\password authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm attempting to create a user programmatically. But while running the app in the device it shows that the user is not created. What's wrong here?
Also, can I create the user and enter the user's details at the same time in database?

```
public class Registeractivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    EditText name,username,age,height,weight,mail,password;
    RadioButton male,female,rb;
    String name_check,mail_check,username_check,pass_check,male_check,female_check;
    int age_check;
    double height_check,weight_check;
    Button save;

    Databasehelper db;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    RadioGroup rg;
    public void rbclick(View view)
    {
        int radioid=rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rb=(RadioButton)findViewById(radioid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_name);
        username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_age);
        height=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_height);
        weight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_weight);
        password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        mail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_mail);
        male=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobt_male);
        female=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobt_female);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_savereg);
        rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogrp_gender);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        db = new Databasehelper(this);
        //EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
                progressDialog.show();

                name_check = name.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name_check)) {
                    name.setError("Your Name");
                    return;
                }
                // male_check= male.getText().toString();
                // female_check=female.getText().toString();
                if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Registeractivity.this,"Enter Gender",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                    // no radio buttons are checked
                }
                username_check= username.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username_check)) {
                    username.setError("Your Username");
                    return;
                }
                pass_check= password.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pass_check)) {
                    password.setError("Your Password");
                    return;
                }
                height_check= Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(height))) {
                    height.setError("Your height");
                    return;
                }
                weight_check= Double.parseDouble(weight.getText().toString());

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(weight_check))) {
                    weight.setError("Your weight");
                    return;
                }

                age_check = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(age))) {
                    age.setError("Your age");
                    return;
                }

                mail_check=mail.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mail_check)) {
                    mail.setError("Your Email ID");
                    return;
                }

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(Registeractivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Registeractivity.this,"user inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(Registeractivity.this,"user not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

/* commented code removed */

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I'm no `java` expert, but perhaps you'll get more information if you look what `getException()` returns for you task. It's documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Task.html#getException()).

Comment: Remove redundant code, improve spacing.